# OpenCV HuMoments produces wrong result

Tags: c++, opencv

This piece of code:

```
int main() {
    Mat input_img = imread("abcdef.png", CV_8UC1); // Image of size 1000*800
    Moments moment = moments(input_img, false);
    double humm[7];
    HuMoments(moment, humm);
    for (int i = 0; i<7; i++)
        cout << humm[i] << endl;
}
```

prints out:

```
0.000789284
1.24093e-07
2.37587e-15
1.48852e-15
-3.19408e-31
4.09704e-20
-2.78098e-30
```

which is wrong. Hu's invariant moments are not that small. I can only remember reading somewhere, the first moment is usually >100, the second >60 ...
Did I miss something?

Comment: You can try looking into this post. Though the issue is different but it also calculate the Hu Momemts. It may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492274/hu-moments-comparison

Comment: Check `Mat::data` for `NULL`, from API:

"The function imread loads an image from the specified file and returns it. If the image cannot be read (because of missing file, improper permissions, unsupported or invalid format), the function returns an empty matrix ( Mat::data==NULL ). Currently, the following file formats are supported:..."

Comment: @Mario The image is not NULL because I can `imshow` it.